# Table Sorter - twitter bootstrapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, tablesorter

I got a rails app with twitter bootstrapping, I have a data table and I just want to know if I should integrate [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) via Rails or should I use jQuery libs?
So I am trying to achieve something like this: http://tablesorter.com/docs/
What are your recommendations? I would appreciate if I could get some how-tos.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using this [rails app](https://github.com/themilkman/jquery-tablesorter-rails), it is actually using [this version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) (not the original)

Comment: @tokhi did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can include jquery plugins in rails as you would normally include any js file.
Just copy the `jquery.tablesorter.min.js` from the archive into `app/assets/javascripts` and add this line to the `application.js`

```
//= require jquery.tablesorter.min
```